# facing a issue in angular site route navigation

Tags: angular, routes

Please help me i am facing a issue in angular site route navigation.
my site url is this in local
http://192.168.17.30:4200/login
on server
https:// ******/login

When i reload the same page with F5 then it come like

https:// ******/login/login

again i hit to reload then site not working blank page comes.

When i navigate to menu then its works fine but in all route when i reload the site or hit F5 same url added in route like
https:// ******/checkstatus/checkstatus
etc...

Please anyone can help what i am doing wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: add related code, it will help others to provide you with a solution.

Comment: Actually i am not clear what i am missing and where to look for this error. this is a routing issue or some code issue or my server routing issue i am using NGINX for this application . locally its not giving such error but when i put build code on my NGINX server route add itself as above mentioned .

Comment: @SolutionwithAnkit can you check how your `<base href="/">` looks like in `index.html` file

Comment: @varundhariyal here is my routing code   import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';



// Guard


// Services


// Components


// Parent Routes
const routes : Routes = [
 
 { path: '', redirectTo: '/quiz', pathMatch: 'full' },
 {
  path: 'login/:user',
  component: LoginComponent
 },
 {
  path: 'login',
  component: LoginComponent
 },
 {
  path: 'profile',
  component: UserProfileComponent,
  canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  data: { title: 'User Profile' }
 }
];

Comment: There might be issue with code in index.html file, can you paste your index.html code here

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti here is my index.html   

<base href="">

Comment: Yeah, there it is, change `<base href="">` to `<base href="/">` and try once

Comment: add a forward slash   <base href="/">

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti let me check this

Comment: Oh man you both are life saver for me :-) .

** Thanks a lot man **

Its working now. 
i tried it before but i missed something may be.

Thanks once again. :-)